# How to correct small typos?

Tags: support, editing

I noticed an answer which had misspelled "Shor's Algorithm" as "Short Algorithm" but when I tried to correct this single change I was prevented since edits require at least 6 characters of changes.

Now it's not like they wrote perfectly but the assumption that questions worth editing will require at least 6 characters of edits seems questionable to me.

Why do we as a community seek to prevent such small edits?

Answer (score 4):

This is a network-wide feature. See eg [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520/276202) and links therein. As you can see from there, you're not the first to bring up the issue, but regardless of its merits, it's not something we can change here. You might try to revive the discussion around it on the mother meta site, if you think you can bring up some new points to the discussion.

It's also worth noting that the limit disappears once you're over 2k rep, and it's also relatively easy to circumvent in general, as you can see from the answers to the linked post.